# Showing an isomorphism on $\Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I am solving the following exercise and will appreciate a little help with some steps. This is the exercise and my solution process is below.
[image]

**1. Show that the reducts are isomorphic**
To show an isomorphism of algebras, we need to show there is a homomorphism $H_1: A \to A$ with an inverse homomorphism $H_2: A \to A$, $H_2 := (H_1)^{-1}$. $H_1$ and $H_2$ must be bijective.

The $H_1$ and $H_2$ must preserve the operations of the reducts. Let´s start with $H_1$.

Define $H_1$ as:
\begin{array}{ll}
      (0,0) & x = (0,0) \\
      b & x = a \\
      a & x = b \\
      Id & x \in K - a, b, (0,0) \\
      Id & x \in K´\\
\end{array}

$H_1(x *_1 y) = H_1(x) *_2 H_1(y)$ must be true for any $x$ and $y$ from $A$.

To see whether this holds, let us look at the two possible cases.

**x and y are in K´**

Then the operation $*_1$ gives $a$ everytime and $*_2$ gives $b$. So we got to check that

$H_1(a) = H_1(x) *_2 H_1(y)$. According to the definition,

LS = $H_1(a) = b$

RS = $H_1(x) *_2 H_1(y) = x *_2 y = b$. Hence $LS = PS$.

**x and y are not in K´**

Then $LS = H_1((0,0)) = (0,0)$.

$PS = H_1((0,0)) *_2 H_1((0,0)) = (0,0) *_2 (0,0) = (0,0).$

Now check the $H_2$ (inversion).

**x and y are in K´**

$LS = H_2(x *_2 y) = H_2(b) = (H_1)^{-1}(b) = a$

$PS = H_2(x) *_1 H_2(y) = x *_1 y = a$

**x and y are not in K´**

$LS = H_2(x *_2 y) = H_2((0,0)) = (0,0)$

$PS = H_2(x) *_1 H_2(y) = (0,0) *_1 (0,0) = (0,0)$.

Hence, we have bijective homomorphism with bijective inversion, so there exists the desired isomorphism.

**My questions:**

A) How do I know that my definition of $H_1$ (and its inverse) is correct?

B) How to proceed with the second part about ring isomorphisms?

If this would be correctly defined, then I think the check for all the cases is quite an easy thing. My problem is, however, whether I can define the homomorphism this way and how to show this is the correct definition.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you describe $K'$ specifically? That would be a necessary starting point. About $H_1$, yes it should map zero to zero and $a$ to $b$. What about other elements of $A$? Where would they be mapped? Note that $H_1$ is required to be bijective.

Comment: @Berci Thank you! No, that is my second struggle. I don´t understand well how $K$ and $K´$ may look. How do I visualize the $K$ generated by two elements? Is it something like their linear combinations?

Comment: Yes, exactly, linear combinations.(with integer coefficients (modulo 4)). Well, $A$ only has $8$ elements, $K$ will have $4$. I think 'complement' means here set theoretic complement.

Comment: @Berci I edited my question so now the definition of the homomorphisms could be correct, I hope. However, I didnt even need to describe the K´, which is suspicious. Do you think of another approach to this exercise, using how the K´ looks?

Comment: Please enumerate the $4$ elements of $K$ and the $8$ elements of $A$. How do you mean $H_1$ as $(0,0)$ for $x\in K$? That would ruin bijectivity.

Comment: @Berci I think the 4 elements of $K$ are $(1,0), (0,2), (1,2), (0,0)$? (Not sure how to make linear combination of modular stuff tho). Still, I am not clear about how the homomorphism looks on the rest of $K$ and $K´$.

Comment: Yes, you can check that the 4 elements you wrote are indeed closed under addition. I'd suggest to try the simple $a\leftrightarrow b$ swap as $H_1$, so all the other 6 elements of $A$ would be fixed.

Comment: @Berci Ah, so now my definition of $H_1$ is in fact the same as you say, right? I mystyped the zero before, I meant identity everywhere except a, b.

Comment: Ah yes, if you meant that, it might work. Verify that it respects the $*$ operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to take $H_1=H_2$ which *swaps* $a$ and $b$ (that is, $H_1(a)=b,\ H_1(b)=a$) and fixes all the other elements, then your verification for part 1 works fine. (Though the description of case 2 could be clearer: 'if $x\in K$ or $y\in K$'.)

For part 2, observe that $b=x+x$ for some element $x\in A$ while $a$ cannot be written so.

Comment: Thank you, I dont understand, however, your reasoning of the part 2. Why this shows there cannot exist any isomorphism?

Comment: I think that would only show the $H_1$ is not isomorhism, but I need to show there cannot exist any other isomorphism.

Comment: First you need to prove that any isomorphism $f$ would take $a$ to $b$. Once it's done, just consider $y=f^{-1}(x)$ for the mentioned $x$. Then we get $y+y=a$.